# Adding Validation To a Form submitted through ajax

Tags: jquery, html, validation

The form is submitted through ajax.

```
function post(url,formId) {
    jQuery.post(url, jQuery('#' + formId).serialize(), function(d) {
        jQuery("#response").load("<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/success.php'; ?>", function() { Cufon.refresh(); });
    });
}
```

I have this form

```
    <form name="checkout_address" method="post" id="shippingF" 
     onsubmit="post('/process.php','shippingF');return false;">
    <div id="shipping-userdetails">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Recipient Details</legend>
    <div>
    <label for="uname">Company:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="company" value="">
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for="firstname">First Name: </label> <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="" size="50">
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for="lastname">Last Name: </label> <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="" size="50">
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for="email">Email: </label> <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" size="50">
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Now I wanted to add validation on the form so that, before the form is submitted it should be validated first. 
If there is error on the form, an error text will be displayed below the field that is error and the form is not submitted.

Im a newbie in jquery.. How to accomplish this?

Comment: jQuery validate: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a jQuery validation plug-in like this:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: @Ken You just add the plug-in as one of the scripts downloaded for the page (it needs to load after jQuery).  Then follow the documentation. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: I don't understand. It looks like you are using `load()` to load a success page. Can you explain how you are loading the form via `load()`?